# Can I force dot/bracket notation?

Tags: objective-c, appcode

For ObjC, I have the choice to use either dot notation or square bracket notation.
Is there a way to enforce (with errors/warnings) a certain notation for uniform notation throughout a project?

Comment: care to elaborate why my question is downvoted?
The question is on-topic in my opinion as of  `software tools commonly used by programmers;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfectly valid question.  Not sure why the downvotes.

When we designed `@property`, the dot came along with it.  There was considerable debate about whether the dot should be limited to `@property` or not.  We landed on "not" because there was too much pre-existing API that kinda sorta felt like a property but would never be re-declared as an `@property` because it really wasn't.

`NSArray`'s `-count` is an obvious one.  That could easily be `@property`.  But then there are methods that fall more into the gray area.

Didn't seem like there was enough value to really warrant enforcing such a rule, hence `.` was presented as (nearly) identical with calling a getter or setter.

The compiler didn't have an option to enforce one or the other then.  And I'm pretty darned sure-- but not 100% certain-- it hasn't grown one since.

Comment: Thank you. Although I didn't mean a compiler error/warning, but an IDE (since I am using AppCode, see the tags of the question) warning/error.

Comment: @Raildex There is no difference;  The errors/warnings you see in the IDE are entirely produced by the compiler.

Comment: Actually, AppCode has its own "inspections" that can report additional warnings and errors. But there is indeed no inspection for this case. Normally, I'd encourage you to file a feature request, but ObjC-specific features will not be a high priority at the moment.